# Connecting Sun Ray 2 to ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, oracle, client

Is it possible to use Sun Ray 2 thin clients to connect to an Ubuntu desktop?

We have 6 Sun Ray 2 thin clients and one IBM server with an AMD processor.

I need to install Ubuntu server/desktop on the server and then connect thin clients to it. It will be used as public computers connected to the internet and a shared printer in our library available for our visitors .

Comment: AFAIK, the only variety of Linux on which Sun Ray Server Software (SRSS) is officially supported is Oracle's own RHEL-based Oracle Linux. There doesn't seem to be much up-to-date information about installing SRSS on Debian-based systems: the most recent I can find is [Installing the SunRay Server Software on Debian GNU/Linux](https://wwwcip.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/~simigern/sunray-debian/). Good luck!

Comment: Have you considered this?
http://www.jopenray.com/
It should, in theory, enable protocols like VNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official Ubuntu supported architectures page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SupportedArchitectures), the MIPS architecture is not supported by Canonical, so you cannot install Ubuntu on the Sun Ray 2 clients.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news* **:\**

Comment: I might expressed myself badly, i don't want to install ubuntu on Sun Ray 2, i wan't to use it to connect to the AMD based server where will be ubuntu installed. I have some experience on installing and managing ubuntu (mainly web servers), but when it comes to thin clients, I'm complete newbie.

Comment: o_O You want to use the existing hard/software from these 15 years old  thin clients to connect to a modern server???  Wow!  Good luck!  You'll need it! (I will delete my answer after you confirm you've read this)

Comment: Are you sure you are answering the correct question? This was about using the Rays to connect to a Ubuntu/Linux box, rather than installing Linux/GNU on them.